# drush "The drush command 'self-update' could not be found."

Tags: drush

I'm trying to figure out why many drush commands aren't working.

`drush theme list` also reports:

> The drush command 'theme list' could not be found.  Run `drush
>   cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have
>   installed new extensions.

I'm mildly certain I installed drush via brew install drush.

Any tips?

Comment: drush pm-list --type=theme works but I don't see why drush theme list doesn't ... https://drupal.org/node/530780

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize http://www.drush.org/ hadn't been updated for awhile. That's too bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self-update` was [removed a while ago](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/167). I'm not sure what the official replacement is, but a simple `git pull; composer install` does the job for me with the latest version (run it in the drush lib folder, probably in /usr/local/Cellar if it was brewed).

`theme list` (and `theme`) don't appear in the [list of available commands](http://drush.ws/) (although `self-update` does, ironically). Maybe you're looking for

```
drush pm-list --type=theme
```

Comment: I'm with Clive, (git's the best way to download and manage your drush instance) but I've never needed to run composer install. I `git clone from https://github.com/drush-ops/drush`. Then I can checkout any version of drush (sometimes functions don't work as expected) with `git checkout tags/7.x-5.9` or whichever is best.